# Not-bing maps on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, controls, maps

Is there by any possibility a library or sth that allows to work with maps on Windows Phone 7 (connect to gps, connect a gps data with a point on the map etc.) and is NOT the control that connects with Bing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/news/releases/11-1qtr/phone7-app.html), which does not use the Bing Maps control, though if you just want different maps (such as OpenStreetMap) you can specify a custom **TileSource**.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use the Bing maps control with other sources http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2010/10/showing-open-source-maps-on-windows.html - although this may one day hit licensing issues.

If you want to write your own map control, there are a few open source projects around - things like http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/, http://wpfsharpmapcontrols.codeplex.com/, http://bingmapscontrol.codeplex.com/ - but I don't know any of those with WP7 or touch support. Given the number of questions I've seen on SO asking for advanced features (like map from isloated storage), then hopefully one will come along soon!

Answer (score 1):

Resco MobileForms Toolkit contains Location library that offers location-related services and lets you select one of 2 providers - Google or Bing. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/Resco-Location-Library.aspx) provides the details.

Any comments are welcome.